# Delphi 5 transparency breaks child draw

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have a control in Delphi 5 like this (following this post: https://tips.delphidabbler.com/tips/74.html):

```
type
  TTransparentGroupbox = class(TGroupBox)
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  end;

.....

procedure TTransparentGroupbox.CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(params);
  params.ExStyle := params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

procedure TTransparentGroupbox.WMEraseBkGnd(var msg: TWMEraseBkGnd);
begin
  SetBkMode(msg.DC, TRANSPARENT);
  msg.result := 1;
end;
```

But I have trouble when it is redrawn. The portion not blurred should be listbox on such a TTransparentGroupbox, but it is not entirely redrawn, as if the background mode would have been propagated to the children but they are repainted on the `TWinControl` level. I have tried to set it back to OPAQUE at the only point I could override, but with no success:

```
procedure TTransparentGroupbox.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
   SetBkMode(DC, OPAQUE);
   inherited;
end;
```

[image]

[image]

The annoying part is, that I have other TTransparentGroupbox instances, with other TListBox instances that do not behave in this way.

The second problem I have is that whenever the visibility of a child control is changed to false, it is not "erased".

Comment: At the bottom of the article you linked it seems to dicuss part of what you are asking along with a solution which is removing the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style which might lead to flicker. The other option is to update to something newer than the 23 year old Delphi 5.

Comment: @Brian Neither options work. Removing WS_CLIPCHILDREN causes the control not to be shown at all. And for now, I have to stick with whatever is, as it is not my decision to take. Please, believe me, I would rather switch myself.

Comment: FYI, later versions of Delphi have a [`TCustomTransparentControl` base class](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TCustomTransparentControl), which does the following: 1) enables the `csOpaque` flag in the `ControlStyle` property, 2) sets its `Brush.Style` property to `bsClear`, 3) enables the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` window style, 4) handles the `WM_NCHITTEST` message to return `HTTRANSPARENT`, and 5) invalidates its `Parent`, and any child controls on its `Parent` which are lower in z-order than itself, whenever itself is invalidated.